# How can I output a php value into a JS file within Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wp-localize-script

I am trying to use  [`get_theme_mod`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) option from php to load into my js file. I've used [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to convert. The `tweet_id` is where I need to place the `$tweet` value outputted.

Any help would be great! (PS: I've registered the script in functions.php already.)

***PHP FILE***

```
<? 

$tweet = get_theme_mod( 'tweets_widget_id' );
wp_localize_script( 'twitter', 'tweet_id', $tweet ); 

?>

<? wp_enqueue_script('twitter'); ?>
```

***JS FILE***

```
var config2 = {
    id: "tweet_id",
    domId: "tw-widget2",
    maxTweets: 3,
    enableLinks: !0,
    showUser: !1,
    showTime: !0,
    showInteraction: !1,
    lang: "en"
};
twitterFetcher.fetch(config2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PHP

[wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is a good time to localize the data. Make sure you target your script and create a name for the object as well as passing an array of data. In this case `twitter_settings` is the object that will be created and will hold all the data. `twitter_settings.tweets_widget_id` will ultimately hold your `$tweet`.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {

    // Get the current data
    if ( empty ( $tweet = get_theme_mod( 'tweets_widget_id' ) ) ) {
        $tweet = 'No Widget ID';
    }

    // Localize script with data to `twitter_settings` object
    wp_localize_script( 'twitter', 'twitter_settings', array( 'tweets_widget_id' => $tweet ) );

    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twitter' );
} );
```

### JS

Access the localized data from the `twitter_settings` object

```
var config2 = {
    id: "" + twitter_settings.tweets_widget_id, // based on comments
    domId: "tw-widget2",
    maxTweets: 3,
    enableLinks: !0,
    showUser: !1,
    showTime: !0,
    showInteraction: !1,
    lang: "en"
};
twitterFetcher.fetch(config2);
```

### Test

(optional) Test to make sure the variable came through ok.

```
<script>

    (function ($) {

        alert( twitter_settings.tweets_widget_id );

    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, the JS file is external however `wp_register_script('twitter', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/menu/twitter.js',array('jquery'),null, true);` How would it work that way?

Comment: I added the `twitter_settings.tweets_widget_id` into the var like so `var config2={id: "twitter_settings.tweets_widget_id",domId:"tw-widget2",maxTweets:3,enableLinks:!0,showUser:!1,showTime:!0,showInteraction:!1,lang:"en"};twitterFetcher.fetch(config2);` as I need the value to output within the "" of the id. Hope that makes more sense what I'm struggling to understand. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need quotes. If you need to make sure it's a string write ""+variable. If you put quotes around it in JS you will only get the characters displayed there.

Comment: Perfect! the `config2={id: ""+twitter_settings.tweets_widget_id` done the trick. Thanks for your help.